# Why lavaan does not work with ordinal endogenous variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, ordinal, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I am working on survey data and try to analyse it with SEM in `R` with `lavaan`

The data has no missing value, and there are 1723 cases.

My model has 2 factors and two ordinal endogenous variables.

And the model looks like below:

```
#model1
model1 <- '
  # measurement model
  F1=~ Q15+Q16+Q17
  F2=~ Q18+Q19+Q20+Q22+Q23
  # regressions
   V1~ V2+ V3+ V4
   HKER ~ V2+ V3+ V4 + V5
   F2~ Ordin1+ V5
   F1~ V5
   Ordin2~ parscor + Ordin1+ F2 + F1
  # residual correlations
    Q15 ~~ Q16+Q17
    Q16 ~~ Q17
    Q18 ~~ Q19+Q20+Q22+Q23
    Q19 ~~ Q20+Q22+Q23
    Q20 ~~ Q22+Q23
    Q22 ~~ Q23
    V1~~ V2 + V3+ V4
    V2~~ V3 + V4
    V3 ~~ V4
'
```

All variables, no matter exogenous or endogenous are ordinal variables.

The program shows two warnings:

> 1. the optimizer (NLMINB),claimed the model converged,but not all elements of the gradient are (near) zero;, the optimizer may not have found a local solution; use check.gradient = FALSE to skip this check.
> 2. trouble constructing W matrix; used generalized inverse for A11 submatrix Error in nlminb(start = start.x, objective = objective_function, gradient = GRADIENT, :

I followed the instruction in:

http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cat.html

and declare Ordin1 and Ordin2 as ordinal variables with `ordered`
but it does not work. And standard errors for all estimates are missing.

Does anyone know what's going on here?